# SQL How to order each entry by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, label, rank

I have a list of customer_ids, the date on which some information was changed, and the corresponding changes. I would like to number each change, by order of date, on each customer. So for example; I have something that looks like the following

```
    Cust_id         Date                information
   -----------------------------------------------------
    12345           2015-04-03          blue hat 
    12345           2015-04-05          red scarf 
    54321           2015-04-12          yellow submarine
```

and I would like an output which looks something like this;

```
    cust_id      change_number        Date             information 
   ---------------------------------------------------------------
    12345          1                  2015-04-03        blue hat   
    12345          2                  2015-04-0         red scarf    
    54321          1                  2015-04-12        yellow submarine
```

This will be quite a big table, so it will need to be somewhat efficient.
There will be at most 1 entry per customer per day.
Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: `Row_number() over(partition by Cust_id order by Date) as change_number`

Comment: ORDER BY is a basic SQL function, so googling that should help. If you need efficiency, then make sure your table has an index on the Date field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Indian said, Try this :

```
 select cust_id,
        Row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by date) change_number,
        Date,
        information 
   from tablename;
```

Comment: Thank you Indian and SNC, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

If you want to order over a change number like that you need to use an inner select like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY [Date]) As Change_Number
    FROM yourTable) t
ORDER BY
    Cust_id, Change_Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY [Date]) As Change_Number
    FROM yourTable) t
ORDER BY
    Cust_id, Change_Number;
```